# How to save base64 encoded binary data to zip using PHP

Tags: php, zip, unzip

I am getting a base64 binary encoded data from an API request response. I need to save it as zip file. I use the code like below.

```
<?php
$zipStr = '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';

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: filename="my.zip"');
$out = base64_decode($zipFileValue);
print($out);

?>
```

But I am getting a SFX zip Archive as downloadable option. which I can`t able to unzip using PHP. I can unzip other normal zip file but not this SFX zip.
Can anybody help me to save the encoded data as zip or tell me how to unzip a SFX zip archive.

Comment: The base64 example you provided (`UEsDB...`) *is* a valid ZIP (starts with `PK...` when decoded), *not* a SFX archive (i.e. not an executable.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to create a temporary file for the zip archive, then use ZipArchive() to add your string to the archive as a file. Try the example below.

```
<?php
$zipStr = 'UEsDBBQACAAIABprdEEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAWAAAAb2JqZWN0cy9Db250YWN0Lm9iamVjdI2SX0vDMBTF3/cpSt9NOhERyTJCl+Gga6VNBZ9GlmWuI21mk0799ka7P50TXR4C9+R3L5ecg4bvpfK2sjaFrgZ+HwS+JyuhF0X1MvBzNr6684e4h8LGWF0m87UU1nMtlRn4K2s39xAazTfALHUtJBC6hNdBcAuDG1hKyxfcch/3PHeQKox9KuSbaetvbdkoFfNSYqEry4WdpXxdzBE86EdUaNWUlcHjPIpmMZlSBPfSOUTCMMljBv7jwiRmJGSATVh0Efj4kMS0fwlJp2QS/Q2mFOQZTTNAognJfmOXhbKyzoTeSEydSx925Yxx/9PRf9Kd/p0q1eKwVphSwuhoNnL315yvt1Pezay5dXHAShqT1PS14QrBo3yKb7lqJGbJiDwj2BbHjeDZSkjxuVR7v72d363Y5gR2goJgN3i49wlQSwcI3kTEMT8BAACvAgAAUEsDBBQACAAIABprdEEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALAAAAcGFja2FnZS54bWxNj00LwjAMhu/7FaN3lzpkiHTdQfDkQUS9StbFWbXtWIsf/96xDzSX5CF53ySieJtH/KTWa2dzNk84i8kqV2lb5+x42MyWrJCR2KG6Y01xN219zq4hNCsA77BJ/MW1ihLlDKScZ8AXYChghQGZjOIuRPg05Ie6Z0Om7FbKtbMBVei0fT7v8aZLAVP7J7BoSG61DydNLwE9Dtbw5y3GP2SaJVzARJGA8XwZfQFQSwcIaf0pNKsAAADwAAAAUEsBAhQAFAAIAAgAGmt0Qd5ExDE/AQAArwIAABYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAG9iamVjdHMvQ29udGFjdC5vYmplY3RQSwECFAAUAAgACAAaa3RBaf0pNKsAAADwAAAACwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACDAQAAcGFja2FnZS54bWxQSwUGAAAAAAIAAgB9AAAAZwIAAAAA';

// Prepare Tmp File for Zip archive
$file = tempnam("tmp", "zip");
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($file, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

// Add contents
$zip->addFromString('your_file_name', base64_decode($zipStr));

// Close and send to users
$zip->close();
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.zip"');
readfile($file);
unlink($file);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the below way and it worked, nice and easy.

```
$folderPath = "/this is your folder path to save the zip file/";
$zipStr = "UEsDBBQACAAIABprd_etc";
$zip_Array = explode(";base64,", $zipStr);
$zip_contents = base64_decode($zip_Array[1]);
$file = $folderPath . uniqid() . '.zip';
file_put_contents($file, $zip_contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
this is the best solution to convert base64 to zip
Source https://stackoverflow.com/a/57585801

<?php
$base64 = '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';
$decoded = base64_decode($base64);
$file = 'file.zip';
file_put_contents($file, $decoded);

if (file_exists($file)) {
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
```