# Convert Base64 string to an image file?

Tags: php, base64

I am trying to convert my base64 image string to an image file. This is my Base64 string:

http://pastebin.com/ENkTrGNG

Using following code to convert it into an image file:

```
function base64_to_jpeg( $base64_string, $output_file ) {
    $ifp = fopen( $output_file, "wb" ); 
    fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $base64_string) ); 
    fclose( $ifp ); 
    return( $output_file ); 
}

$image = base64_to_jpeg( $my_base64_string, 'tmp.jpg' );
```

But I am getting an error of `invalid image`, whats wrong here?

Answer (score 316, accepted):

The problem is that `data:image/png;base64,` is included in the encoded contents. This will result in invalid image data when the base64 function decodes it. Remove that data in the function before decoding the string, like so.

```
function base64_to_jpeg($base64_string, $output_file) {
    // open the output file for writing
    $ifp = fopen( $output_file, 'wb' ); 

    // split the string on commas
    // $data[ 0 ] == "data:image/png;base64"
    // $data[ 1 ] == <actual base64 string>
    $data = explode( ',', $base64_string );

    // we could add validation here with ensuring count( $data ) > 1
    fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $data[ 1 ] ) );

    // clean up the file resource
    fclose( $ifp ); 

    return $output_file; 
}
```

Comment: i have very smart solution 
 $filename_path = md5(time().uniqid()).".jpg";
 $decoded=base64_decode($base64_string_img); 
 file_put_contents("uploads/".$filename_path,$decoded);

Comment: I had just raw base64 data without any prefix or so. therefor I had to change $data[1] to $data[0].

Comment: @rcpfuchs if you have just raw base64, then what is the need to use $data,use it direct as written in asked question

Comment: If you are expecting either, you can use array_pop().

Comment: @Trinh's answer is better for non-raw base64 strings:`file_put_contents($output_file, file_get_contents($base64_string));`

Comment: You can improve this function with check if $data has really more elements.

Comment: @JaroslavŠtreit validation is noted in the comments

Comment: I don't think this is an efficient way to go about it. Using explode on a large file say 2MB will substantially take a lot of computation time.

Comment: @NafiuLawal this is `O(n)`. Feel free to do some benchmarks, but I don't think there's much optimization that can be done without going closer to the metal.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst you are right especially in php

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst Not much optimisation you can do?? I hope you are joking! Your code goes through the ENTIRE string. Why not do explode(',', $base_string, 1) to stop after finding the comma?? Reading the first 20-ish chars from a string vs (potentially) several MBs? In any case, file_get_contents($base64_string) is waaaay more efficient.

Comment: @DanieleTesta you'll have to provide some benchmarks to quantify waaaay more efficient :)

Comment: fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $data[ 1 ] ) ); this not worked for me. instead of this I used fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $base64_string ) );

Answer (score 90):

An easy way I'm using:

```
file_put_contents($output_file, file_get_contents($base64_string));
```

This works well because `file_get_contents` can read data from a URI, including a data:// URI.

Comment: ingenious - thanks for answering. just remember you'll actually NEED data:image/png;base64, at the beginning, or else file_get_contents() will fail.

Comment: This solution is better than the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, better & simpler solution. You can make file extension (if needed) using the identifier string `data:image/png;base64`.

Comment: what is $output_file here?

Comment: @sd077 In the example in the question, $output_file is an input parameter containing the value of the filename to save the image.

Comment: Does not work on all servers, example:

`PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): data:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in ...`

Comment: @Ov3rfly your server config `allow_url_fopen` is `OFF`. you can re-enable it in `php.ini` and try again!

Comment: @HenryTrần: Changing server config is not an option here.

Answer (score 54):

You need to remove the part that says `data:image/png;base64,` at the beginning of the image data. The actual [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) data comes after that.

Just strip everything up to and including `base64,` (before calling [`base64_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.base64-decode.php) on the data) and you'll be fine.

Comment: Tried different solutions, but this one worked everywhere.

Answer (score 23):

maybe like this

```
function save_base64_image($base64_image_string, $output_file_without_extension, $path_with_end_slash="" ) {
    //usage:  if( substr( $img_src, 0, 5 ) === "data:" ) {  $filename=save_base64_image($base64_image_string, $output_file_without_extentnion, getcwd() . "/application/assets/pins/$user_id/"); }      
    //
    //data is like:    data:image/png;base64,asdfasdfasdf
    $splited = explode(',', substr( $base64_image_string , 5 ) , 2);
    $mime=$splited[0];
    $data=$splited[1];

    $mime_split_without_base64=explode(';', $mime,2);
    $mime_split=explode('/', $mime_split_without_base64[0],2);
    if(count($mime_split)==2)
    {
        $extension=$mime_split[1];
        if($extension=='jpeg')$extension='jpg';
        //if($extension=='javascript')$extension='js';
        //if($extension=='text')$extension='txt';
        $output_file_with_extension=$output_file_without_extension.'.'.$extension;
    }
    file_put_contents( $path_with_end_slash . $output_file_with_extension, base64_decode($data) );
    return $output_file_with_extension;
}
```

Comment: This worked as a charm! Thank you a lot!
Exactly what I was looking for. Just changed a little bit to match my specific requirements and got everything to work.

Comment: FYI : `$output_file_with_extension` is declared inside the `if`, then called outside, which will cause an "Undefined variable $output_file_with_extension ..." on some cases.

Answer (score 10):

That's an old thread, but in case you want to upload the image having same extension-

```
    $image = $request->image;
    $imageInfo = explode(";base64,", $image);
    $imgExt = str_replace('data:image/', '', $imageInfo[0]);      
    $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $imageInfo[1]);
    $imageName = "post-".time().".".$imgExt;
    Storage::disk('public_feeds')->put($imageName, base64_decode($image));
```

You can create 'public_feeds' in laravel's filesystem.php-

```
   'public_feeds' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path() . '/uploads/feeds',
    ],
```

Comment: `laravel's filesystem.php` AND `Storage::disk('public_feeds')->put()`  helped me to solve my issue which help me to out files inside the folder we want

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$image_no="5";//or Anything You Need
$image = $_POST['image'];
$path = "uploads/".$image_no.".png";

$status = file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
if($status){
 echo "Successfully Uploaded";
}else{
 echo "Upload failed";
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: This is not an answer or even relevant to the original question.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst It actually is an answer and it is relevant to the original question. Although not a good answer or very much helpful to OP.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.

```html
<?php
$decoded = base64_decode($base64);
$file = 'invoice.pdf';
file_put_contents($file, $decoded);

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score -5):

```
$datetime = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
$timestamp = strtotime($datetime);
$image = $_POST['image'];
$imgdata = base64_decode($image);
$f = finfo_open();
$mime_type = finfo_buffer($f, $imgdata, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$temp=explode('/',$mime_type);
$path = "uploads/$timestamp.$temp[1]";
file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
echo "Successfully Uploaded->>> $timestamp.$temp[1]";
```

> This will be enough for image processing. Special thanks to [Mr. Dev Karan Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10059176/dev-karan-sharma)