# PHP get pdf file from base64 encoded data string

Tags: php, pdf, header, base64, encode

I have a base64-encoded string containing a pdf. How to create a `.pdf` file from this encoded string using php?

Something like `Content-type:application/pdf` in header function?

[this is the base64 encoded string](http://jenson.in/base64pdf.txt)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Base64 string to an image file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153776/convert-base64-string-to-an-image-file)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Try this piece of code

```
$pdf_base64 = "base64pdf.txt";
//Get File content from txt file
$pdf_base64_handler = fopen($pdf_base64,'r');
$pdf_content = fread ($pdf_base64_handler,filesize($pdf_base64));
fclose ($pdf_base64_handler);
//Decode pdf content
$pdf_decoded = base64_decode ($pdf_content);
//Write data back to pdf file
$pdf = fopen ('test.pdf','w');
fwrite ($pdf,$pdf_decoded);
//close output file
fclose ($pdf);
echo 'Done';
```

Comment: Thanks Samy, This is what I wanted..Cheers..:) But I've got a -Ve vote for my Query! Was there anything wrong in my question?

Comment: For DomPdf I only needed `$pdf_decoded = $domPdf->output()` and lines from `//Write data back to pdf file` onwards. (To whom it may concern)

Comment: It not work well, I tried to unlike this answer but I don't can.

Answer (score 37):

With this you can create and open the file... but maybe this is not the answer to the question

```
$data = base64_decode($this->Get(self::Body));
file_put_contents('file.pdf',$data);
```

The answer is echo the content with a header :

```
$data = base64_decode($this->Get(self::Body));
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
echo $data;
```