# How to get image binary data in php after submit form

Tags: php, jquery

I have added image corp feature using http://www.jqueryrain.com/?7VoW4dx3.
This plugin provide binary data of image with base_64 encode. I get this data in php after submit form for create image using php GD library.

I have tried to send binary data using hidden field, textbox and textarea but when I have print binary data it's display [removed] beginning  of the binary data.

So can you please help me how to get binary data php side for create image. Or also provide another way to save/upload image.

Comment: You mean how to post image binary data with 63 base encode huh ?

Comment: yes exactly. I want to image binary data for create new image

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022101/php-get-pdf-file-from-base64-encoded-data-string

Comment: @guest271314. I am not able to save binary data in text file. If i am able  then no need to ask then question.