# Can i display/open/preview base64 pdf without store in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I am storing file into storage folder then show that file into browser and when close that file then remove that file from storage but I want directly show into browser and also can be download without store. This is working but storing file.

```
$fileFromAPI = $apiResponse->file;
$bin = base64_decode($fileFromAPI, true);
$path = config('pdf_paths.file') . $id . "/";
if (!is_dir($path)) {
    $oldmask = umask(0);
    Storage::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true);
    umask($oldmask);
}


Storage::put($path . 'file_' . $fid . '.pdf', $bin);
$pdfread = 'storage/' . $path . 'file_' . $fid . '.pdf';
return response()->file($pdfread)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36987211/1427878

Comment: its not show proper ... its look like this https://imgur.com/a/MsAvafq

Comment: `$bin = base64_decode($fileFromAPI, true);
 header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
 echo $bin;`

Comment: That _is_ what the content of a PDF looks like, but your browser did not interpret it as a PDF - which means, your attempt at setting the header has likely failed. Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled?

Comment: i think header not included if i am remove header ... its give same output means its show  base64_decode code

Comment: i added base 64 code into this link...https://imgur.com/gxdKIJn when i am converting online its give proper output

Comment: BTW thanks bro for give me your time ... i found solution based on your knowledge
 return response($bin)
            ->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution just  set header and return it.

```
         $fileFromAPI = $apiResponse->file;
            $bin = base64_decode($fileFromAPI, true);

            return response($bin)
            ->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
```