# Laravel 8 - Create a PDF file from a API return string data

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

In Laravel, I am trying to create a pdf file from an API response PDF data string. How can i create and save PDF in storage directory physically in Laravel.

Check the image below:

[image]

In this image i hit an API and got a response in variable data->labelDataPdf . I want to create a pdf file using this string value.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: check the question again i updated.

Comment: You answer is much help and i find the way to do. Check the answer of this question.

Comment: The partial answer i got here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022101/php-get-pdf-file-from-base64-encoded-data-string. Hope this help to other people.
I am not able to post the answer her as i ban for answer by stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Try this [package](https://packagist.org/packages/crabbly/fpdf-laravel), it implements a popular PHP library (http://www.fpdf.org/) for pdf generation in Laravel