# file_put_contents returns empty image, but text isn't empty?

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
$img data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2w..........

file_put_contents('myimage.txt',$img);    
file_put_contents('myimage.jpeg', base64_decode($img));


Here is the Output I get:
90KB myimage.txt file
0bytes myimage.jpeg file
```

I tested the text filehere: [Here](http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/) and it seems to be working.
 Thanks for the help!

Apache 2.2.23

Comment: Thank you for this code... so what to do with it?

Comment: Refer to my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153776/convert-base64-string-to-an-image-file/15153931#15153931).

Comment: You need to strip off the data-uri stuff. base64_encode/decode do NOT need or understand that.

Answer (score 3):

Well if $img really does contain the 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' data inside it, then base64_decode() will fail because it doesn't contain true base64 data.

```
$strippedImg = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,','',$img);
file_put_contents('myimage.jpeg', base64_decode($strippedImg));
```