# How to send image to WebApi using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can I send an image to webapi if I have url of that image? I had tried with using fileupload and succeeded.

Now I need to send it without using any control like fileupload.

Code which I tried now:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#btnUploadFile').on('click', function () {
        var data = new FormData();
        var files = $("#fileUpload").get(0).files;
        // Add the uploaded image content to the form data collection
        if (files.length > 0) {
            data.append("UploadedImage", files[0]);
        }
        // Make Ajax request with the contentType = false, and procesDate = false
        var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/api/fileupload/uploadfile",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data
        });
        ajaxRequest.done(function (xhr, textStatus) {
            // Do other operation
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Maybe U encode image to base64, send to controller, and decode this and save.

Comment: Thanks @Jarosław Osmólski, can u suggest any code sample for the same?

Comment: JS encode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript
PHP decode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153776/convert-base64-string-to-an-image-file