# convert base64 coded images to file input element

Tags: php, base64, image-uploading

I am using a scanner API to scan images in my web application, its running well. But its create an image to view with src coded likes this:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS....">
```

I want to upload this image using my simple code witch post (input file) to PHP file in ajax by element id

```
<input type="file" >
```

So how can I convert this img element to (input file) element, or how can I post and upload this coded src

Thanx

Comment: use textarea to send the "string", decode the data and save it as file

Comment: show your php code plz

Comment: i think the solution here covers you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153776/convert-base64-string-to-an-image-file