# How to fetch data from ajax in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image, upload

I am passing image from a form to a php page using ajax. Problem is that the data is not getting fetched and giving a blank output. Following is my code:

test.php

```
<!-- Help taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446281/passing-image-using-ajax-to-php -->

<form name="saveImg" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="saveImg">
<input type="file" name="imgVid" id="imgVid">
<button name="submit" id="submit">Upload</button>
<img src="skin/images/process.gif" id="procimg" height="32" width="auto" style="display:none;" />
</form>

<div id="msg"></div>











<!--jQuery-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    saveImgfunc();
});

function saveImgfunc(){
    var form = new FormData(document.getElementById('saveImg'));
    var file = document.getElementById('imgVid').files[0];
    if (file) {   
        form.append('imgVid', file);
    }
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'core/img.php',
        data : form,
        cache : false,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false
    }).success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

img.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "Data can be fetched here";
}
?>
```

Kindly help me with this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try  print_r($_FILES)

Comment: What shows up in your web access and error log related to this?

Comment: if you are using ie is not working becouse of FormData suport ie10+

Comment: @tiGer. print_r($_FILES) is working. but I need to check it into $_POST.

Comment: I am using chrome @madalinivascu

Comment: Nothing @DavidHoelzer

Comment: @VineetMishra If absolutely nothing shows up in either the error or the access log, that tells me that the Ajax request isn't even hitting the server.

Comment: print_r($_POST) and check console.

Comment: Its hitting @DavidHoelzer. Because print_r($_FILES) is give image attributes passed from ajax.

Comment: Blank like this () @tiGer

Comment: @VineetMishra If that's the case, what is in the log file?  That can be very useful in figuring out what's going on.

Comment: print_r($_POST) giving output - Array
(
)

Comment: print_r($_FILES) giving output - Array
(
    [imgVid] => Array
        (
            [name] => img1.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpD4BA.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 83480
        )

)

Comment: Add `method="post"` attribute to your form. The normal methods for forms is GET @VineetMishra

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

to this:

```
if(isset($_POST['imgVid'])){
```

---

Because you are not posting `'submit'` to the php. You code of this line

```
data : form,
```

has just this:

```
form.append('imgVid', file);
```

Comment: Tried. But no output :(