# Base64 data; should I include the "data:xxx" before the actual base64?

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, base64

I need to send an image that has been converted to base64 by JavaScript, to a server. Lets assume I don't know anything about the server, except where to send the data. The image is a `.jpg`, so when JavaScript converted it, it prepended `data:image/jpeg;base64` to the actual base64 data. So the result is something like this:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEA8ADwAAD/4V3gRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAg [...]
```

When researching on this topic, I found posts on SO that say keeping it will invalidate the base64 [(here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153776/convert-base64-string-to-an-image-file).

So, in general, should I strip the `data:image/jpeg;base64` or keep it?

Comment: Since `,` isn't a valid base64 character, you can easily split the string on the comma and get the last segment.

Comment: Thanks. Follow up question: why does JS insert that there then?

Comment: It's the content and encoding type of the attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will definitely need to remove the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` if the server is only expecting a `base64` string. If you don't know *anything* about the server, make sure it's setup to receive a base64 file at the very least.