# How to save cropped avatar with laravel

Tags: javascript, php, image, laravel

So my website (built with laravel 5) allows users to upload an image, crop it (with croppie.js), but here's the problem - the cropped image I get is based 64 data URI and I don't know how to upload it.

My trials:
1. Initially I used a form to post it - but now I get base64 URI, I can't put it in some `<input>` element in the form, like this:

```html
<form.....>

 <div class="actions"> 
     <button class="file-btn"> 
         <div>Upload</div>
         <input name="original" type="file" id="upload"/> 
     </button> 
     <div class="crop"> 
         <div id="upload-demo"></div> 
     </div> 
     <div id="result"></div> 
 </div>
 <input id="image" type="hidden" name="image"> 

</form>
```

If I can bind the generated base64 URI to the hidden input it will be perfect! But I just can't make it..

2. I can post base64 to controller - then what? Should I just store the very long string in database, or generate a image at the server side, then store in the server?

Seems the first approach is easier but I have been googling for 4 hours and got no answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- crop image, generate base64 uri
- post base64 uri to laravel endpoint
- decode base64 uri on server side and store image

This should help with the decoding part:

[Convert Base64 string to an image file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153776/convert-base64-string-to-an-image-file)

Comment: Thanks you are pointing me to the right direction, but I'm still pretty much confused about the file object on server side. 
So I got a file using `file_put_contents('image64.png', $avatar_data);`, but how do I use the file? What I need is a UploadedFile object, which requires a path by its constructor, but how can I specify the path in this condition? When I try `$avatar = new UploadedFile('image64.png',$original->getClientOriginalName());`, it throws a unknown error.

Comment: Solved! 

`file_put_contents('image64.png', $avatar_data);
 $avatar = new UploadedFile('image64.png',$original->getClientOriginalName(),'image/jpg',null,null,true);`

The trick here is the last parameter - setting to true or it fails unknownly.