# Laravel 4 - unserialize(): Error at offset while save base64 image

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to upload  base64 image to server. 
I've already try many answers, but i always get the same errors.

[image: error]

Links that i tried

[How to save a PNG image server-side, from a base64 data string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string)

https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/39wclp/how_to_convert_an_base64_image_string_to_an_image/

[Convert Base64 string to an image file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153776/convert-base64-string-to-an-image-file)

This code below should work.

```
$image = base64_decode(Input::get('image_cropped'));
$image_name= 'file_name.png';
$path = public_path() . "/images/" . $image_name;
file_put_contents($path, $image);
```

Comment: Show us an example of a base64 encoded PNG image that fails. Also `unserialize()` doesn't decode base64 encoded strings.

Comment: this error is not related to your image creation. you write something to session store. its laravel framework session store handler related.

Comment: the base64 png image is very large.

Comment: Are you coding the image from a canvas or something like that?

Comment: from canvas! using method toDataURL().

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the form sent from request the image encoded starts with `data:image/png;base64`, so try with:

```
$img = explode(',', Input::get('image_cropped'));
$img_name = 'file_name.png';
file_put_contents(public_path().'/images/'.$img_name, base64_decode($img[1]));
```

This worked for me.