# Showing the data from mysql data to php page using select

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am using JQuery Line Control Plugin for textbox, which include both images links text(which can be styled in either format) and it is proving me the html code for that which saves in MySQL database.

For Example :

If in Line Control Textbox I insert an image and a paragraph it saves in MySQL the below result

```
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4RDgRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABAE7AAIAAAAHAAAISodpAAQAAAABAAAIUpydAAEAAAAOAAAQyuocAAcAAAgMAAAAPgAAAAAc6gAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA...and a lonbg garbage text like this" alt="" height="151" width="139"/>
<br><br>Summis cernantur possumus, sunt arbitror ea comprehenderit, ne multos quibusdam &lt;br&gt;distinguantur de multos est cernantur e e laborum arbitrantur do dolor e &lt;br&gt;excepteur iis laborum fugiat fabulas si nescius quem nostrud vidisse. Labore &lt;br&gt;pariatur in praetermissum qui laborum quem nam <br>
```

How can I show it in php page with the image ?

I know JQuery also so the solution with jquery will also accepted.

Comment: it is an image encoded to base64. you can simply echo the string or convert to real image with php.

Comment: how can I convert it to real image?

Comment: take a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15153931/2418529)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change this according to your filetype.

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
$data = "/9j/4AADADJdjw8A........and so on"; // Get this from somewhere
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $data . '" />'; // To Display the image
```

**EDIT:**
Your Base64 image code is probably damaged. I ran your code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcgh4kwh/) with another image and it works just fine. Maybe you should check whether your Base64 data is being truncated by the database.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. If you drag the code to your right you will see that the image is followed by paragraph and the image itself is in `<img>`  tag

Comment: In that case you could just echo the entire query result into the page using PHP, right?

Comment: Yes exactly. Please Help

Comment: I am trying to display it by `echo` but it gives me the text correct but image is broken

Comment: Can you show us the exact output of the echo statement without any truncations.

Comment: Sorry, I Will not be able to give us you a screenshot. It is showing me the paragraph which is below the image tag `<img>` and the image shows me a broken link icon that's it.

Comment: Your code runs fine with another image as seen here  https://jsfiddle.net/tcgh4kwh/ . Your Base64 image code is probably damaged.