# How to rewrite base64 image to direct image in PHP

Tags: php, base64

I have a PNG base 64 image data and i want to automatically convert it to a direct image (by direct image i mean like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkZ87.png))

Here's an example of the data I'm trying to convert, in this format.

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEAAAABACAYAAACqaXHeAAAYjklEQVR42u1bB1RVV9Y+rwAPePRH U5oUEVCRpvTeexcRECkqgkFRUBQVKWpEAVs0EzNjZhJTNTE9JibGRGMmGmNizKRYxkTHQjIpGqPC +/69L5LfkkxmLFmz1njX+ta997x77rv7298u5z4QAMT/MsRdAu4ScJeAuwTcJYCwc43zHcVba53F onJrsb3bWexa5yLef9BVNBZpfNfPslO+0uUmNi9xZ5g81uap2dTqJZ7u8BFblvuLwJFmdkIIY3EH tt+dgJYKa/nONS5iW5ezwbqZttn3ZKs/XDbF/MkFEzRrm0o0zy2u1JxoKdd8PX+C1V8XVQy+v6nM qdbX3eDV1FCrwOo8JzEp2/G24nclYNd9LmJBqWX6HxrsguryjPe3lxmjq9oUXVPNsKTSFO0VZlhe pUGHBEssmWyFeSUaVGWaY/3ckR4vrhojtnaNvq24hoA3yTN3Cuz1N1e7yuvyTbZVZ6q/7a4xRXeN OZZNNpMMby0zQ3OpCeYXG2NBiRFaysyxeLI1OqoHY26JFTqmewZuXj5aPLbU/7biGgJe7XK+Y9ix 2kU8NM/eY8449cWOySZoL+83dG6hGvVjjSTMyDVEdYYKU9NVmFdsitYKayyZMgiNxaSGaV4xDy8O Ehtbx9xWXEPAg3PsbwobZtuLB34DDzU5iIZxFsUzclSYlWeAGTn6qM1SYUKcLsqT9FGZYoCyRBUy gpSYmKBC43hTtJRbkwpsMXu8BRZMco9fNdtPdNX73FZcQ8DEFM1NoSrLUtTkWomanF/HtDxrkRpk uLg4RoG8cB2Mi9JFbphSG+unr2USkgOUyI80RHKgkXZSij5mjqVwmGCJ2lwzVGcaYWqufeLc8mFi zkT324prCNBRym4KjjZ6YqSrgRju/OvwcDIQfkN1NqQF6SE/QhdR3vK+zDDjvmnjR2pzw/QQ76fE lBx7VGY7kyp0MCHBAFMzTZAdbYecSDOEj1LHhfuYiduNawi405uTlXh0QpoTMsLU2hGuRhdmlY7Q PtqVgaw4N+3s2sIf2qaH9DZWjkJ+uAIxvgbaglgLLKpLxrRif1gYi1iVrhAGercXvysBZobivvbp wdrSHL+LDz+y6cfGaRmX1y6M60tNCNHu3PX+xfe2r7+wel4EUkYrkBE9BEWpruhcmIOsJO8TMpkY fccboTu9yYRIqyn231E3Jb3vsSee1m595qm+9a0ZvXWVMdqA4IS+R+6f17djUznSQs0xeVwAqkuC MLN0zHkPGyUbr/yvJ0BGblIqlbSXC0c7c+FkbyF0dRTXXDIhx6/h1U33wGO4r/bRPy3vu3T4Xnx/ sB0tDfnnnnmg4vLFIx3YuDwfzST9qnH+mBWp6OtOF4kd6ULcm3L7cVsJkMvlQldXlwhQiEDfISIv 1U/4DzUXicPkwtPRWNgNMhPFWX7Zp/ctwquPTtee3tei/fHze/HVngX44WAb8M0a4Ot1OPJOq3ZO RXDvwgRlX0u8wLJUsfGpUiGevgO4YwQEeDuKzMRRItDDXMyOlouCAH3h7GglIgJd/L77qE2Lf67F D58swbHdC3Dg5Vk4uL1Bu+f5mX2PLE3uva/CsffJYhl2VAksTpahxF/2d1eNUDhbCDHE/PbijhMQ MNRM3BMqRBKpQAiFsLM1M/zbm/N7vjvS2ffp6w147Y+F2hULsi4/fn9lb2d91KXnxou+D6cLfDhT 4MclAm9VyzAtVIZCX0WZQi77784BVxPgTwQkRg0nBVjYt6erKlaOM1vdEKf38Mos+ZPPN7p9u77S 4eyOuS442Giofb7GtPfpNQV9OxrttD+2CXzfLnConh5phUDfcoGtZTLMiZH1BTjIZpsY9BN5u3DH CPDxslctn5vetvfFum+O7ZyFN/4yEd0zgtCVIUNXCsV1ksCbDXbAn5yBTgW+mC20F8jjWEkgo4/M FThAKsCqfiUsT5NhUYJAgKNyipNGVwQ564gAp1vH7SJAd6AKMAG8lY0NmtF7YiUufNFBSW4h2upT MLc6Bs3JeqDsiwWxAt15JtA+5AWsNZIMPdsq126abNP38vK8y2fbdLULKQF+MVcGrBb4aBapIFqG ugjZhQXxioQdU+WC8cYt4pYJsLOzSyOE6OjoCD09PaE21Be2GpWoKRq96MG2OJw7tBg/fLyYCEhG 64xYVIToHQ4bIpa4W4pUr0E62ce7PHpPrnLrW1Pmcik3JbI3IasEz29/9/yZ1Z7nVyQLtCbK8G27 TCJoS6kMjTGCw6GnNkw+rDFWIW4Vt0xAUVHRY25ublF8bGBgIPUrnoNlI9NHiSPNk3xw+XgXeg93 YFljKmJD3O5TKmSaq+c/WW3/+cFtD/TWNnWgtrFNWzY+9/K+dWO/+2G56tKWCQI1IQJPlPQTcH4p hQ6FwhIKn0hP9XNCrkOKI+jcPG6VAIOVK1fud3Bw8OP4VxubCWszndDcAMXXpSkun/7z4BLtqQPt 3+17ru5IoI/T1F+6QWWo+qGLr9fj9Gd7zu/qTD3/jxbVZS3ngm6BvVQN6iMFmuJkOMyhsEZg/zSB KTGmaJwai0E2pgU/95j/ElddI7sWt0qA7UsvvdQzYsSIICubwcLV0ca/KsXq2+jRLp2DbK2V1RPj XKZPyjDNSPDRETKllCSvaoulzdvBoOryRh+cX2PXiw56jM7+JMj7UwsF2sjbc0n2D42T4SKNf/UH H7RTOC1uSMGIYYNncOgZ6Kv+BfRImfqSOvX19aU8dTVuigBDQ0PpZrTpPfvssz1TptbcO8bXs3B6 nvuZwozQL4NDIsocHZ0KR3l7p7u6uAx3crRXazQaKUf8XDFk/VCr5GOOdXtr8bAnVQCDfuOX95fA i/cKPDKe84BALfUCHz06Fn1n1+PgtnpUjA38zthIf5DakPPOL8PQQFcYGxkKGxtrYWxsPPDMt94H ODo6CldXV2Fvb+9fX9/w2f2rl/VUpzuifFwCamrrtLW10zF+/HiUlJTwXpualnYyNDR0O5EwysjI SHoYheLnNYLpC/VDT+NJf+A+y/8n4IoKuCFaECeQ6yW02x8qBX7cAHzZhZwk7yc05moxyNr012Fr KUxMTIkAG8Hfe9sIGDRokPDx8akpKi45l54SezkzyOJ8dmKQtrhkIsrKyjF27FiEhYUhPT0dBQUF qKyspPEyxMfHv5aQkCBoXCJwYGvJGbQLWwKBB4ZQ7Cv7e4Euge8oF7wySfRVBYvehjCh7a72xp9W lhxMiPCYbmigb6VU6ggdHd0bwAsyIyNjYWNrK0xN/wMChgwZ8psgr4uRI0cuYu9OmTIFE0snICU+ 7NL27a//tHnz5stkbF94eLg2JCREO27cOGRmZkpKKC0tRUZGxk+2trZeKpVKesiBLcZTvQGbg9D7 kDeONKuxvUpoHysRfRsLRO+WUtH78HihXUwlsZn6AjtD0clzWEHcc/wSVCp9MXjwYMlR/xEB+fn5 v4q8vDyRn5fP3htGhqC4uBgTJ/Z7nJSgJan3LV26VLtu3TptXV1dX3R0dG9WVhaoTErhMLAn8u5n 77sPHSrUarX0EFbGyrRNk2y+fb7aDBvGKvperhRa7gR7FgmcbhbYOZUWRZQMO1IFkjzEBzRFZ6Dz vB6cFM3MzG6OgOsz5NXgm7i7D2XvdyQmJoK9y15lIvicJe/u7o7Ro0eDjEdkZCRLXgqHAXA4pKSk 7Ke9gsgQHq6OwpSeyYBK8mPjxZGfSPK9y65Ugq7+RHiZzj9vpK4xk1eGApODZb0ymdzn18KT1cUE sPH/MQH/amNGXVxcLIMCA8+QGiTDCwsLQeoAe5pV4e/vDz8/P4wZMwYU68jOzpaQk5OD3NxciYSk pCQt3S5A8iBBn3xJJAz9ZLa4pKXE10ul8NIyXgVeIYNIOE1K2JAv0JLACVEGWhBN+9XGhModG31T BFhbW98AS0tLnizz8PCYTJ7+lD1fUlIsKYCNYuMZKSnJ8Pb2BsU/AgMDERcXJyVBBpPD1zAZTBhd 9yZJ1WBg3TDYRCSdIql/R6vAC9TtfVBHZY+S3rNl4ideB5xb3F8OF1I1WErriGE28sd/yXgrK6tb I4A6uhtATY5IS0uL5PgtLy+XEhp7csDrA0ZGREQgKChI8jwbT56WkJycjNTUVOkaToisBp5L4VJJ c4TK0ER4WomZPS39MX+8SeCBPIFwZ/Gih7Wo+GlZ/5KYX47Mj+vPA3Hu8sPUSl1jDTsqICBASoI3 TcCvSH8IxfrGCRMmSLLPy8u/Ynga0sgwimkyMkmKdzac4z82NlY6TqAxzg8SCWlpEglsPIcQkXOO KsVcIzPrQf528kXnycs/kAJ21VDrSytFO1PBrbOSVHCKVUAhInWFvJIsCZBfpAByv/pdJH2nCA4O lpLgAAEDhrOS/y0CKIFdA6r1ejExMR8MZHD2XlpaKkk/GWPzE5GTnUCGxEsG9ye+CCn5RUdFgeYh Nj4O8QmJSGAlEFGSEtLSpVAoGD8W2XmZiIiJ/SbMx/Ufnzb09/8vlPe/AVLriWB+wHQvsZIXQqyQ BygPtFFXOCtSBl2lPH3ACC7P5CRJAUwAG0sEmFK1iaXPyql0h5Dx8t8kgGXErHHbamFhIYYOHVrI XufszfJlSWekx6OkOBY1VTGYOCGKFBBJ8g+XYp/BocAkRLEaUtMQk5GFOFJMPCmBw4MVkZZFJJZm oKA8B8WTC5EzvgDJ0T59L1br47lyWuwEK35SyoWL1Cbqi0guhb0UBq9X9VcC7gwtjZVT5fL+XoC9 TwoVlIS5FKqcnJwK6HsOc77hcOVnJ3J2UStu92+FABvPXRQpYA7fhKWbQJ5kT6enR2NSRTQObk9E XfUYkncolcAQhISESqUwnLwfQdIPJ8mH3DMDMRs2InJsAaKIvOgoCo+4GCTlxCG3Jgn1e0gJtKgp a85D1R8LkTEjFuOSPZHjb/ylvp6uvq5SapeNXqoUJzgMDl8ph7wcdrPSeYXEb8llj0JMUFLWoxxU TGF1gB3GSZqfnRM1K5eJGDZs2DO/SQAzyskpNydHpKelPcrxy55jSUdGRdJxGCZXRODx9SGYUORP +SAYoSFBCKYEGBoRiTDyenh2LkLyCxDyhz8h+u//QFhRCcISkxAeFk73iEB8RjSyZ8Rh8luRSJoS gvkfF2Ap0lD1cTiyyrORlJzYozYyHmagKxNeNkL8ZZx4Cff1l8RXKgSmhirhaGdNDywbzgssUpyG PP42G8vhysZynuFQY+9zzhqAp6fny5QzTH91NajQkQvf0FFBQdFjdkQlUzwnRyEuvj/GAyMCERYz GjljR2Nq1RjMrQtEakogyT4QQcFEAHk+hIwNX7UW4VOmInhmPcLvXY7g3DwEx8QiJDiEwiQMMUnU JOVFICo9GImFkSjqSETz+TSUbAtEdnEayiaVUUUJ3kthYBzorC82VVpu+ZbK495ZOpiXpMaokSPg NMR5NyW3qaTSTZSAP2OvD/QkTAQbS9VLQuqVZM3HrAYKkU7uGrmdvp4AXTOFZtFEu5pzlW7TUeQ6 CaluORjlMwojR3gj1jkZ0a7xiB8RiYxof4wvGoqklACMHO4BN/ehcPfzRmDBWHg1z4F7ejLcwoMx NCIAAQnRCAkNQ1BYELyDRsBz9DD4RIxAeEIoEjKjEV8Uhsz2MCTOCEROUQYKJ44jEibC08ur28TC Zk7AyGEYPdwJgx3cYGPvpo0IGdU3JsDns6zs7N6BhowM1FKc91IlAK08pcrDOSvxSu5h8DmHM4XJ l2zrDQqQK2XxCbrZOOx0WcLRIX34wukS2jXrEKITi/ftz2C/Q4+EN2y/wEzrVthZWaPZbBWeH7wH sy2WwMHDE1WaevzZ8gVssn4VTZoOBDuHY1TQSPi6+6HcphbzrJahyqYBIa4RGDFmOMI8w5E9LBeR w6PhF+SLRO8UpAdmIT0lHR6eXgdHB3ifqK5MRVfrOPy5q0ibmRLRl5GZJUmdvc4epn4Fvr6+6Orq krrRKMpFXIo5dKWKRPmLS/UVYnqpUmTekANsHW0WJ+nk4CPHb/CJ0w9Ya/44dtkdxQHHHkwzmI99 DqfwN6dzeMr6LXzgcJZIuoR4ZRYe1mzDGVfgIZsXUaQ3BV85AQeIpO2DDuGMM/CI7TbYGTngYctt OE4r3gP2X+Nzx4vYafcFvPR8sMhwNY47AE9ZvYURCn+8Zn0Ir2kOIXZEAnzH+B9LiPb/7MiuJpw8 0IqlTYW98YkpWpY6e589yl6nNQrHt+T9gT0bzkQwOIQHGjQOD1LLBxQC9tcthkRcAhn0vt1ZfGT/ HSr0Z2Kr1V+xz+4M6gxasHvQcWm8Wn8eXrDaj88dLmGCQQ3Wm23BF46X8aDmOSxUr5KOnyRjKlWz sG/waWy23o0UZT72D+6R5tcZtOJ5q3045gjco16AZvVq/M3hAhHzDWr05+NNUtcem5MId4tCeEwY Gcch6EkP7Qcf3wAEBQZJ6w42bKABYwVQ0waq+6AOFl5eXqD8IIEVweA5vE7hsGDiiJRt1+eAePbo ezan8L7NGWw0ewm7rI7R+UlUq+bhbeuj2GdDBlnswjvWX2K71ScIUkZpHzDZik8HXcD9RES5bh0+ tv0e+23OYoPpVsTqpPWZyywPJStzL+6l++63PYtJqno8Y76H5vyIBvViNBuuwkHbb/GBTQ8eMXsN r1kewk6LI4gYGnPBP9j/Rzc3N8yePQdLlixFe3s72tra0NDQwGVNMmTJkiXSOSe61tZWLFiwQDJ2 2rRp0vUU81IO4GOuDNyvcEKkCnH6RgIUmXhH85WEvZan8a7mJJqMViBJmaPdpfk79mhOYJv5x3hP cwrrTDbDVmbXu8HoOXxsdQ5rTB7vsxGDLzbpd2K35jgOWn2Ply0+1Iboxh6PVqRc5rl/tTyFSXr1 2Gy6S/q83qAdC/S7sd+yh+79Ffg7dmu+xOvmn8HdxKvJVGMymiR9oaWlBZ2dnaivr8ecOXOwZs0a qeRxi97d3Y1FixZJ7yeWL1+OxYsXS8pobm6WPuM5kydPxtq1a7k/4Bb8MQqFJUTCgzcQECfPxFum x/BXs1Mo15v5g4vc41kaXxotT73M4++YfYU63RY8bUShYdaDTJ0irNJ/HAfMvkW3etNPJjKzY5GK ZMzT7cQzV67ZYvwO8pXl2GFyGLtpfqXOLDyu3on9Zt+gTtWKJr1OvGd2Bq+akOdNj2K36Zd0/Als hF0NPxQtw4+yV5cto+RZVYUZM2ZgxYoVUofKLTqPNzU1STmBjWfDOf7nzp0rnQ8ohskhr39NbbI+ yV9QLlDeQECsPANvqD/Hu0YnEaqMe/FKwxQyML7T6BiqdebiCf23sMfoBAqUFejW24S9RmewQvVn VOjMxHvGp/FH/RdRKJ+Mneqj2KY+hBplE14x/JjmH0Wp8h48ov+6NKdWdyEadTrwntFp/EG1FU8a vI23jf6Ol9QfwlZuV8utCRMwb948Sd7sad6zCpydnftYBWxkY2OjpAj+bP78+VLS42v4nNXD85Yu Xcp9wjd0Tw0vmIiAG/qAhARZFt5WHcf7qq8Ro0h75QoB8fE0vlN1DLtUJ3CPYiGe0n0H76pOo0Ax CSuVj2KvqgfdOo9ivLwK76hOYoveu2hWrpbmvKT6CHnyMjynu186b1Wuwxbdd2nOWYxTTMYcBRFA x8uUG7FY+QB2q77CC6oPYSOzn84rQlrUHGMD2Yja2lrU1dVJhg28meJj9jD3A+x99jwTwNJn5cye PRsLFy6UcgAZLRHARlFo3UBAnK8Ixmz5vZhDcJa533eFgKRgWQw6FX9Bh2IjsmUluFf+R6xTbEGM LA3z5J14TLET0xQLMEQMRYt8LbYq9+JV5Sd4QvE28uXlR02F+Ylpsvl4WvEutis/xYvKDzFPseK8 ubA8yfO3Kz+TiM2TleFlxUFsUr4BK5lt3QABbCAbwTHP8cxkcAgweHzmzJkSGRwK7HlekPEYK4ff YwwQSHH/MwG/tBYwJ+QTSglp/MPHwG+gCqGcT81jOx3Xy4W8TU/or6P9Quqo29TC+ClDYfQEHRfS 5wUGwnCXk3A74Sa8PjcWph38voIQpBKq152Fe4+PCOxxEC7baMyX5syzE06HHYXLIZXQ32AmLA4O Ee5HNMJmq0zIHegak6sJ4Nfr/DaaZc1NENd0ljwbyAazkXwN9wU8xoRw88OfsQKoabp05Xnu6F+J 6V5h2fC6cX6by0tSm+vG+H8BVFfO1df9b4Al5YAeNprBsmepswpGjRr1DdX+U9wUVVRUSKDs/r2x sfEqW1vbo1wWqe6fomX+p7Q/FxgYeNrc3Hz9Vd/1+/6Z3E1uKlqhzlGr1Stp6buQ+vc63iuVynvo MzcuEoQpdM18GptExwO/uIwiBPLvOFeU7Xy153+RgLv/M3SXgLsE3CXgLgF3CbhLwP8c/g8GH6Dq cuzJZQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

As another note i don't want to put it in an `<img>` tag

Comment: Do you mean save it somewhere? If you want to display it on a website, you're going to have to put it in an `<img>` tag.

Comment: @Jaime I want to translate this [link](http://voltiac.ml/services/JavaPlugin/serverv2.php?port=25565&ip=mc.prison.run&g=icon_raw) into a image link so that i can put that into a '<img>' tag on another website

Comment: You could probably do this here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153776/convert-base64-string-to-an-image-file, at this point you could just save the file though, and not process it through php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a file from that base64 like this

```
$file="assets/images/picture.png";
$data="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA..."

$data = str_replace("data:image/png;base64,","",$data);
$data = base64_decode($data);
$myfile = fopen($file, "w") or die("Unable to load image!");
fwrite($myfile, $data);
fclose($myfile);
```

then redirect to that image with

```
header("Location: ".$file);
```