# Laravel base64 file move into one folder

Tags: laravel, base64

I have a `$data` variable with a `base64`: It's either an *image* or a *file*.

I want to move this file into a folder... but It's moved as empty file.

**My code:**

```
$file_name = Input::get('file_name');

$image = base64_decode($data);

file_put_contents(public_path('/user_attachments/').$file_name, $image);
```

Please anyone help?

Comment: In user_attachments folder it will create just empty image or docs..

Comment: My $data is base64 file. $data = data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA...........kSuQmCC

Comment: The problem is that `data:image/png;base64`. This turns the `$data` an invalid image data. Try without the `data:URI scheme` (`data:image/png;base64,`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Base64 string to an image file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153776/convert-base64-string-to-an-image-file)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You **cannot** include the `data:URI scheme` (`data:image/png;base64,`) inside `$data`.

You can remove the `data:URI scheme` using the `explode` function, which will return an array with two elements, and before use `base64_decode`.

- `$data[0]` => the data:URI scheme.
- `$data[1]` =>  your data.

Use it as follow, using `,` as delimiter. Example:

```
list($dataUriScheme, $data) = explode(',', $data);
```

Or without `list`:

```
$data = explode(',', $data)[1];
```

**And then** Try the next code:

```
$fileName = Input::get('file_name');
$fileStream = fopen(public_path() . '/user_attachments/' . $fileName , "wb"); 

fwrite($fileStream, base64_decode($data)); 
fclose($fileStream);
```

or

```
// The final filename.
$fileName= Input::get('file_name');

// Upload path
$uploadPath = public_path() . "/user_attachments/" . $fileName;

// Decode your image/file
$data = base64_decode($data);

// Upload the decoded file/image
if(file_put_contents($uploadPath , $data)){
    echo "Success!";
}else{
    echo "Unable to save the file.";
}
```

Comment: This one also file create in folder. but it was empty.

Comment: Your error is, surely, inside your `$data` assignment. Show this code.

Comment: My $data is base64 file. $data = data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA...........kSuQmCC

Comment: The problem is that `data:image/png;base64`. This turns the `$data` an invalid image data. Try without the `data:URI scheme` (`data:image/png;base64,`)

Comment: Thanku so much.. I got it. @tomloprod

Answer (score 0):

To do it the "Laravel way", you should use the built in Storage/Flysystem driver.

Create a "disk" in the `config/filesystems.php` disks array, something like this

```
'user_attachments' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => public_path('user_attachments')
];
```

Then you can save the file thorugh the Storage facade like this

`Storage::disk('user_attachments')->put('filename.txt', $contents);`

There is other ways to achieve this aswell but this should work

Read more here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem