# How to convert base64 in to image in php?

Tags: php, rest, api

I am new to write  web services for iOS and android applications in both applications they will upload an image from front end in base64 string format so come to android working fine but in iOS not working fine.I followed the following code plz suggest any one if any mistake.In the file path i am showing the data what iOS developer sent but how to show image preview instead of data?

```
        $image = base64_encode($image); //$image is base64 string sending from iOS       
        $output = $currentdate.'.jpeg';
        $destination_path = 'upload/'.$output;
        if(file_put_contents($destination_path , $image)){
        //$result = $output;

        $data = array ('imagename' => $currentdate);
        $where = array ('user_id=?' => $userid);
        try {
            $result = $db->update ( 'users', $data, $where );


            $result = $image;

        } catch ( Exception $ex ) {

            Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('FurrekaLogHelper')->throwError('SQL ERROR: ' . print_r($e, true));
        }
```

Comment: have you looked  into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153776/convert-base64-string-to-an-image-file

Comment: Can you print the "base64" code you are getting? It will also help the iOS portion of code where you encode and send the data.

Comment: base64_encode? shouldn't you be decoding it

Comment: @Pable yes i print the base64

Comment: so i am getting the encoded data from frontend