# Uploaded file by ajax not getting data in php controller in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am using ajax to upload a photo in Laravel. URL is working fine but data is not receiving in function in a controller.

**HTML Code**

```
<input type="file" id="photo_input">
```

**Ajax / JQuery Code**

```
$('#photo_input').change(function(){
var formData = new FormData('#photo_input');    
$.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url: home_url+'/upload-image',
       data:formData,
       cache:false,
       enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success:function(data){
               console.log("success");
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log("error");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

**PHP Code in Controller**

```
public function uploadImage(){
  $data = Input::all();
  print_r($data);
}
```

**Response from function in a controller**

```
array(
);
```

I haven't used `<form>` tag in html, I want to upload it directly. Do I need to add `<form>` tag?
Is there anything which is missing?

Comment: @SagarGautam I am not using the form for this, do I need to add <form> tag for this?

Comment: Yes, create a form for the input and on submit do ajax request:

Comment: @Omkar see this question. might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously

Comment: And yes you can do it without form as well!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#example-form").submit(function(){

var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        data: formData
    });
});
```

Comment: @milo Thanks for answering but I am not using <form> so can you please suggest how do I upload file without using <form> tag (if possible)?

Comment: You can use base64, post base64 data with ajax;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36281449/2693988

Later use PHP to image method;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15153931/2693988

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
<form method="POST" id="photoform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="photo_input">
</form>
```

And accordingly ajax request should change like this:

```
$('#photoform').submit(function(){
var fileupload = $('#photo_input').val();    
$.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url: home_url+'/upload-image',
       data:{
           file: fileupload,
       },
       cache:false,
       enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success:function(data){
               console.log("success");
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log("error");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: You can also do it without form as discussed in this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously

Comment: Your code wont work because this is not a way to upload a file using ajax. You will have to use formdata to upload files.

Comment: @Farsay it will definitely work. I have used it in such way.