# How to convert base64 to image in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel

I am developing api in Laravel 5.4. I will receive the image in base64 format. How can I convert the base64 to image in Laravel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Base64 string to an image file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153776/convert-base64-string-to-an-image-file)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a PNG image server-side, from a base64 data string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511511/how-to-save-a-png-image-server-side-from-a-base64-data-string)

Answer (score 5):

this solution will deal with all image types

```
 $image = $request->input('image'); // image base64 encoded
 preg_match("/data:image\/(.*?);/",$image,$image_extension); // extract the image extension
 $image = preg_replace('/data:image\/(.*?);base64,/','',$image); // remove the type part
 $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
 $imageName = 'image_' . time() . '.' . $image_extension[1]; //generating unique file name;
 Storage::disk('public')->put($imageName,base64_decode($image));
```

Comment: What is `$image_extension`.. ? it's not defined here.

Comment: After perform preg_match function $image_extension variable will be containing  the image extension

Comment: Great bro, you save my day. God bless you

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

function createImageFromBase64(Request $request)
{
   $file_data = $request->input('image_file');
   $file_name = 'image_' . time() . '.png'; //generating unique file name;

   if ($file_data != "") { // storing image in storage/app/public Folder
       Storage::disk('public')->put($file_name, base64_decode($file_data));
   }
}
```

Comment: this does save the file into the folder, but it gets corrupted and not usefull

Comment: Could you first try with the png image?

Comment: do you mean the actual image? if that is what you mean it works pretty well

Comment: May be the base64 image that you have sent using api is jpg image. The above code saves it .png. So it gets corrupted. So could you first convert png image to base64 and use the above code.

Comment: Lol, I already tried that. I used the same type as it is before upload. and it does not work

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: I did it with php.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't return any data within the image. It's a blank image...

Answer (score 0):

1- use package intervention image

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$logo      = ImageManagerStatic::make($request->logo)->encode('png');
            $logo_name = Str::random(40) . '.png';

            Storage::disk('s3')->put('products_seller/' . $logo_name, $logo);
```