# How do I send an image to a PHP API using VueJS?

Tags: php, vue.js

I am trying to send an object which contains an image using Vue to a PHP API but honestly I don't know how, 
I have my form

```
<form @submit='sendData'>
<div class="input-group">
     <label for="name">Name</label>
     <input type="text" @change="getText" name='text' id='text'>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
     <label for="photo">Photo</label>
     <input type="file" @change="getImage" name='photo' id='photo'>
  </div>
 </form>

export default{
data(){
  return {
myData:{
   text:'',
   photo:''
}
}
}
```

and the `getImage()` like this

```
getImage(event){
  let formData = new formData();
  formData.append('photo',event.target.files[0]);
  this.myData.photo=formData;
}
getText(event){
this.myData[event.target.name]=event.target.value;
```

}

```
sendData(event){
event.preventDefault();
this.$http.post('myapi/api/user',this.myData);
}
```

I don't know how to access this image in my PHP API and upload it to database.
I tried accessing $_FILES but it's an empty array

Sorry seems the problem is that I am sending some other data too and not only the formData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to send an **image** to an **api**.

1. You form should specify the type de data you must send for

   your form. you should add this.

   ```
    <form  enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="myData.text" />
     <input type="file" class="form-control" @change="handleUpload($event.target.files)" />
    </form>
   ```

In your script you need to set this methods

```
 data () {
    return {
      myData: {
       text: '',
       photo: null
      }
     }
    },
    methods: {
        handleUpload(files) {
          this.myData.photo = files[0];
        },
       saveProductImage () {
          let formData = new FormData()
          formData.append('text', this.myData.text);
          formData.append('photo', this.myData.photo);
          
          // Send here
       }
    }
```

Please check the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)

Comment: sorry because I ignored some part as I thought it wasn't important but it was the reason it isn't working, I updated the problem if you may help me, I'd be thankful, sorry for that