# include jquery signature into PDF with FPDF

Tags: php, jquery, pdf, fpdf

I'm using this jquery plugin to capture or draw a signature.

http://keith-wood.name/signature.html

And FPDF php plugin to generate pdf

Now I must include signature into pdf...

With FPDF I can insert an image, but I have problem exporting signature to jpeg/png (I don't even know if is possibile)

How I can do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the page you gave link to ([this one](http://keith-wood.name/signature.html)) in `Save/Restore` tab you have possibility to save it as a base64 encoded picture (jpeg or png).

So you can use that and to save base64 encoded picture as a file [here is a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153776/convert-base64-string-to-an-image-file)

> The problem is that `data:image/png;base64,` is included in the encoded contents. This will result in invalid image data when the base64 function decodes it. Remove that data in the function before decoding the string, like so.
>
> ```
> function base64_to_jpeg($base64_string, $output_file) {
>     // open the output file for writing
>     $ifp = fopen( $output_file, 'wb' ); 
>
>     // split the string on commas
>     // $data[ 0 ] == "data:image/png;base64"
>     // $data[ 1 ] == <actual base64 string>
>     $data = explode( ',', $base64_string );
>
>     // we could add validation here with ensuring count( $data ) > 1
>     fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $data[ 1 ] ) );
>
>     // clean up the file resource
>     fclose( $ifp ); 
>
>     return $output_file; 
> }
> ```

To clarify variable `$base64string` is a string that in  your case is generated by plugin, and `$output_file` is a filpath where to save the picture.