# decode base64 image on php get blank image

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, base64

I'm trying to decode base64 image on php but i get blank image with black screen showing that windows doesn't support this type of file.

Here is my code

```
public function uploadfoto(){
    $img = $_POST['foto'];
    $img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $filedir = "./assets/upload/presensi/mx_" . mktime() . ".jpg";
    $filename = "mx_".mktime().".jpg";

    $result = file_put_contents($filedir, $data);
}
```

I get the image from my webcam and here is my view

```
<form id ="inputfoto">
    <div id="my_camera" style="width: 320px; height: 240px;" class="center"></div>
    <!-- First, include the Webcam.js JavaScript Library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/dist/js/webcamjs/webcam.js"></script>

    <!-- Configure a few settings and attach camera -->
    <script language="JavaScript">
        Webcam.set({
            width: 320,
            height: 240,
            image_format: 'jpeg',
            jpeg_quality: 100
        });
        Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
    </script>
    <div id="results" align = "middle" >Hasil akan tampil di sini</div>
    <input type="button" value="Take Snapshot" onclick="take_snapshot()" class="center" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="saveSnap()" class="center">
</form>

<script language="JavaScript">
    function take_snapshot() {
        // take snapshot and get image data
        Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
            // display results in page
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = 
                '<h2>HASIL</h2>' + 
                '<img id="foto" src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
        } );
    }
    function saveSnap(){
        var file =  document.getElementById("foto").src;
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("foto", file);
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("POST", "<?php echo base_url();?>asisten/presensi/uploadfoto");
        ajax.send(formdata);
    }
</script>
```

And here is the
[Blank Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgF7G.png)

What's wrong with my code? Thank you very much for your respond.

Comment: Is this *really* python?  I think you may have your languages mixed up.

Comment: This ain't python

Comment: Sorry, i forgot the language, i mean php.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Base64 string to an image file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153776/convert-base64-string-to-an-image-file)

Comment: @Alex no, i've removed the data:image/jpeg;base64 in my code. That question have a problem that didn't remove the string data:image/png;base64. But even though i've removed that string, i stil get a blank image.

Comment: why you do this `$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);`? also str replace only works if the search part of the string is exactly the same. the answer i marked as duplicate has a better way of doing it

Comment: This code does not produce any output but you mention the browser. Are you actually sending the file to the browser? Have you inspected the file first, rather than adding some layers of processing before diagnostics?

Comment: @Alex I tried to remove that code but the result is still the same.

Comment: I've edited my code so i got the image from my webcam with webcam.js

Comment: Bro I've already answered your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51628533/webcam-js-implementation-on-codeigniter-get-error-while-saving-image ... why post a clear *duplicate* if you haven't even looked at your original question to see if it has any answers???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
This code works for me.Please check it

$image = $this->generateImage($_POST['foto']);

public function generateImage($img)
    {

        $folderPath = "uploads/";
        $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $img);
        $image_type_aux = explode("uploads/", $image_parts[0]);
        $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
        $name = uniqid() . '.png';
        $file = $folderPath . $name;
        file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);
        return $name;

    }
```