# How to convert base64 encode code to image from android to php

Tags: php, android, codeigniter

I am writing app services for android app. I am using codeigniter. From android i am getting base64 string. I am trying to convert it to image. They are sending like $_POST[ base64string ] and i am converting like below.

```
          $data=base64_decode($_POST['signature_image']);

          $im=imagecreatefromstring($data);

          header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

          imagepng($im,$loc_url.$imagename1);

          imagedestroy($im);
```

but it is not converting to image.We are using other server and there also we are using same app services. it is working there. I don't know what is the issue. I have tried increasing

```
  ini_set('post_max_size','250M'); 
  ini_set('upload_max_filesize','200M');
```

in my controller and model file. But it is not working. Please help me what is the issue and how it is resolve?

Comment: What does your data string look like? Does it throw any errors?

Comment: %2F9j%2F4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD%2F2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsK%0ACwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGBYUGBIUFRT%2F

Comment: It contains data like above.

Comment: At a glance it looks like it might need to be urldecoded before base_64 decoding too.

Comment: they are not sending data in url.

Comment: it is not working with urldecode also.

Comment: You have not told what exactly was base64 encoded on Android side. Saying that it was an image will not do. You have to be specific. And then you should tell us which image firmats are accepted by imagecreatefromstring().

Comment: Pretty strange that you use imagecreatefromstring() as  Android will not have encoded a string base64.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is that `data:image/png;base64,` included into base64 string. you need to 1st remove that and try again like bellow.

```
    $encoded = explode( ',', $_POST['signature_image'])[0];
    $data= base64_decode($encoded);
    ....
```

Comment: No it is not contain data:image/png;base64. it is looks like below:

Comment: %2F9j%2F4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD%2F2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsK%0ACwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGBYUGBIUFRT%2F2wBDAQMEBAUEBQkFBQkUDQsNFBQUFBQU%0AFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBT%2FwAARC

Comment: @Mythili Please refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153776/convert-base64-string-to-an-image-file) may be solve your problem