# Saving base64 image to server not working in PHP

Tags: php, json, image

Iam getting base64 image in a json like below format

```
{
"profilepic":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPAAAABGCAYAAADyxhn6AAAMYml..." 
}
```

I have a PHP code like below, where i decode this base64 image and save it in server, i tried to run the code and am not able to see the image in particular folder location.

Can anyone help me to identify the problem here?

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");


$str_json = file_get_contents('php://input'); //($_POST doesn't work here)
$response = json_decode($str_json, true); // decoding received JSON to array
$photo =  $response["profilepic"];

// Obtain the original content (usually binary data)
$bin = base64_decode($photo);
// Load GD resource from binary data
$im = imageCreateFromString($bin);
// Make sure that the GD library was able to load the image
// This is important, because you should not miss corrupted or unsupported images
if (!$im) {
  die('Base64 value is not a valid image');
}

// Specify the location where you want to save the image
$img_file = 'test/'.uniqid().'.jpg';

// Save the GD resource as PNG in the best possible quality (no compression)
// This will strip any metadata or invalid contents (including, the PHP backdoor)
// To block any possible exploits, consider increasing the compression level
imagejpeg($im, $img_file, 80);
$imgPath = 'http://serverip/'.$img_file;

?>
```

Please help me to identify the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Base64 string to an image file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153776/convert-base64-string-to-an-image-file)

Comment: i tried this, not working

Comment: What have you done so far to try and debug this? Up to which part does it work, and where does it start going wrong?