# Andriod Image Upload to Php Server

Tags: php, android, server, base64

I am trying to upload image from my android application to a php server but I can't seem to make it work.

The image is being converted to a string, as i have tried displaying it in a textview. The image also uploads to the server successfully but first the image size is 0.1kb.

I have tried all kinds of image and the image is not displaying. So I think the problem is with the php code.

Here is the php code I am using:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "User Images";
$image = $_POST["image"];

if(!file_exists($target_dir)){
    
    mkdir($target_dir, 0777, true);
}

$target_dir = $target_dir ."/". rand() . "_". time() . ".jpeg";

if(file_put_contents($target_dir, base64_decode($image))) {
    
    echo json_encode([
        "Message" => "Saved",
        "Status" => "Ok"
        ]);
} else{
    echo json_encode([
        "Message" => "FAILED",
        "Status" => "Error"
        ]);
}

?>
```

Here is the code am using to upload the file to the server

```
url = "MY URL";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, response -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }, error -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }){
          @Override
          protected Map<String, String>  getParams()throws AuthFailureError{
              Map<String, String> params =new  HashMap<>();
              String imageData = imageToString(bitmap);
              params.put("image", imageData);
              return super.getParams();
          }
        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

And the code to convert the image to string

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] imgBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

        return Base64.encodeToString(imgBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can't get uploaded file using `$_POST`, use [`$_FILE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) instead.

Comment: Still not working the same issue it get uploaded but not displaying and the file size is still 0.1kb for an image of 40kb `$image = $_FILE["image"];`

Comment: maybe image is wrong uploads from client side? Are you doing multipart/form-data content type.

Comment: am using json volley to upload the image

Comment: can you post image upload code?

Comment: I have updated the question with the upload code

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15153931/9289072

Comment: there base64_decode content writes in file

Comment: can't really understand you @FirdavsKhodzhiev please how is this line suppose to be `if(file_put_contents($target_dir, base64_decode($image))) { `