# How to convert base64 to image/png Content-Type in php?

Tags: php

I simply have the following code to generate an image from base64encodedString:

```
<?php
    require_once 'phpTextToImage.php';

    $img = new phpTextToImage;
    $text = $_GET["text"];
    $img->createImage($text);

    header("Content-Type: image/png");
    imagepng($img->image);
    imagedestroy($img->image);
?>
```

Inside `phpTextToImage.php` there is a few lines of code:

```
class phpTextToImage {
    public $image;

    function createImage($text) {

        // "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";

        // how can I print here image to access it as an image/png?
        $this->image = base64_to_png($text, "image.png");
        return true;
    }

    function base64_to_png($base64_string, $output_file) {
        $ifp = fopen( $output_file, 'wb' ); 
        $data = explode( ',', $base64_string );
        fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $data[ 1 ] ) );
        fclose( $ifp ); 
        return $output_file; 
    }
}
```

I would like to use it the following way:

```
?text={{base64encoded}}
```

I have tried the following solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15153931/2725435

but nothing is printed on the browser.

I have used the following source to get base64:

https://codebeautify.org/image-to-base64-converter

with the following image:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what went wrong with it? Have you researched how to unencode a base64-encoded string? For example looking at `base64_decode()`?

Comment: yes, I will add it to the question within a minute.

Comment: Code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11511605/892493) will help.  `data:image/png;base64,` is not part of the base64 encoding and needs to be parsed to determine the image type and removed if present before decoding.

Comment: As a general note, "it didn't work" is rarely a helpful comment; you need to tell us what _did_ happen when you tried that code.

Comment: @IMSoP of course you are right.... thank you;) I should attach some logs, but there are no logs;) Just nothing happened on browser;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've actually written *more code than you need*, probably because you've put together different examples without understanding them.

Firstly, the code in your `base64_to_png` method is for *saving the image to a file*; but you don't want a file, you just want *the data that would be inside that file*. So instead of the calls to `fopen`, `fwrite`, and `fclose`, you just want to return `base64_decode( $data[ 1 ] )` which is the raw data of the image.

Secondly, the function [`imagepng`](https://www.php.net/imagepng) takes an *object* (or "resource") that you have *created or loaded from file to be manipulated*, and *saves it out as a PNG*. You can't pass it a filename, or a string of data, directly; since you don't want to *manipulate* the image, you just want to display it as-is, you don't need this function and `imagedestroy` at all.

If you have the raw data of the image (from the previous point), then all you need to do is `echo` it, to send it to the browser.

Comment: Ok, let me try your solution from 2 and 3. You might be right. I am not good with php, but I need it to the other project. Need some time to check it and try;) Thank you. Will be back soon

Comment: First of all thank you for your clarification. Yes, I totallt misunderstood the example;) Now it works and it is really simple;)