# Save Base64 ZIP string as ZIP File - PHP

Tags: php, file, base64, save, zip

I'm receiving a Zip file encoded to Base64 on a JSON Callback
How can I save that as a Zip file?
I know how I can base64_decode that but I'm having an hard time saving that as a normal Zip file.
I'm working with PHP

Thank you for your help!

### EDIT

It is solved. I just need to base64_decode the string and save it as a temp.zip file and then extract the content from that temp file. What I was trying to do was extract the content directly from the base64_decoded string which I guess it's not possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save base64 encoded binary data to zip using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490112/how-to-save-base64-encoded-binary-data-to-zip-using-php)

Comment: If it was already a zip file before it was base64 encoded, then just base64_decode it and thats the zip file, so save that to disk as xxx.zip

Comment: What exactly gives you a "hard time"? What problems/errors do you get? Base64 doesn't care for the content. After decoding it's just binary data that you write to a file.

Comment: I'm sorry, but sometimes we just make a big storm inside a small glass. I was trying to do something I don't need to. Yes, it was already a zip file before and I just need to save it as a simple zip file after I base64_decode it.
Thank you!

Comment: @Zachary the OP already receives a b64 encoded zip file, there's no need to zip the data again.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
It is solved. I just need to base64_decode the string and save it as a temp.zip file and then extract the content from that temp file. What I was trying to do was extract the content directly from the base64_decoded string which I guess it's not possible.